# Как изменить место сохранения сгенерированной модели через artisan?

Tags: laravel, model, artisan

Начал изучать Laravel.

Столкнулся с одной непоняткой: при создании модели таблицы (через artisan) она создается в `app/`, что не очень хорошо, учитывая, что этих таблиц может быть больше 40.

Как изменить место хранения моделей?
Решения не нашел. Везде говориться: "Да, можно поменять место хранения моделей" и все. Ничего более.

Кто знает как это сделать - поделитесь знанием.

p.s. Если важно - проект в шторме, тип - composer project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Создаёте директорию `app/Models`
2. Модели создаёте с учётом п.1: `php artisan make:model Models/MyModel`
3. Получаете свою `MyModel` в пространстве имён `App\Models` в `app/Models/MyModel.php`

Чтобы перенести `User` туда же, надо изменить `namespace` и там, где этот класс используется (например, в `config/auth.php`)